# Should I think about GUI at beginning of project?

Tags: c, windows, user-interface

I want to start a **Process Manager** project in `C` and it's suppose to have a *Graphical User Interface*. It's my first *GUI* project and I have no idea about it. After some searches I found that I should use `winapi32` libraries.

My question is:

Should I write my project like a *Console-based* one and then I add GUI to it or I should think about *GUI* at beginning of my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to say that it's best to write the application as a command line application, then write a wrapper in GUI. This way you get the most flexible application with a total separation between the GUI and functionality.

But I won't say it! :-) 
From my experience it's very difficult to totally seperate the GUI from the application, and thus you should built it with GUI in mind. Your code must open windows, report progress, react upon GUI events, so you must be well familiar with the GUI system you use.

But you must also maintain a separation between the GUI and the functionality as much as you can. For example, make your callbacks short, and direct the funcionality to non-GUI parts of the application. If you need to report progress during long calculation, pass a callback to the calculation algorithm instead of mixing GUI progress commands within the algorithm.

You also must bear in mind that most (if not all) GUI system can do GUI commands only within the main application thread, and build the program accodingly.

So in summary - yes, think about GUI at the beginning, it will be easier this way, but also keep a good separation between the GUI and the functionality,

Answer (score 1):

Why changing the program during development? Just design it like it should be in the end.

Comment: I have no idea about windows GUI. Should I learn it and then I start my project?  or I can add GUI after I made it?

Comment: @NimaAhmadi: I would say: Learn about GUI first. Your insight might have impact on your design.

Answer (score 1):

You could design your program in a way that enables you to use both, text and graphical user interface. Offer an abstracted interface to the core functionality and use it from the text and the graphical interface.

If you want start top-down and not bottom-up you should choose whatever you prefer to start with a text or graphical interface that calls stub-versions of your interface.

Answer (score 1):

*Why write your project like a console-based one, since it's gonna end up with a GUI?*

If there are any things you want to try it out first (like you don't know how to do a,b or c), sure you can implement that as a side project.

---

But as far as your main Project goes, **that's what I'd do :**

1. Carefully **plan and design**

   - **What** is it gonna do?
   - **How** are you gonna do it?
   - What should the **User Interface** contain in order to fully accomodate what you need
2. Coding
3. Test and Debug.
4. Repeat 2 & 3 until perfectly satisfied.

---

**Hint :**

> - **A.** I wouldn't suggest you to add your GUI to an existing console app, 'coz this will most likely lead to messy code and/or a messy UI.
>     ;-)
> - **B.** Always **study** before trying to implement anything. You simply can't imagine how much **your knowledge of what can be done
>     influences what you can do *(and most likely what you'll end up doing)***.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an user interface, you can use `QTCreator` or Visual Studio forms projects...

`QT` is an excellent way to make cross-platforms and cute interfaces... `Visual Studio` forms are usable only in windows platforms.

When you're working with any of these technologies you have to put "componentes" in a "window" a then code them...

Comment: It's suppose to be a C project, Can I use Visaual Studio forms without using C++?

Comment: C++ includes Most of the C functionality... But the componentes works with clases, because visual studio works with MFC... So if you wanna try with C in windows, you have to deal with WinApi... There is a nice tutorial... c winapi http://zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/

Comment: Of course, You can work with the functionality and design as two distinct aspects... First you've to model the functions that "WinAPi's componentes" will use... and then program the program's functionality